# Fiddler - error when simulating modem speeds with Web Services

Tags: web-services, timeout, fiddler

I have an application that pulls data from several web services.

The application is correctly using fiddler as a proxy for all these web service requests, and everything works as it should.

I would like to simulate the web services servers being slow, so I enabled "Simulate Modem Speeds" in fiddler (without modifying the default rules file). Now most of the responses I get back are:

*ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.*

If I disable the "Simulate Modem Speeds", everything works fine again.

Is there a way to get this to work, or a better way to simulate a web services response being slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, it certainly sounds like your webservice is configured to timeout if it doesn't get a given request within a certain period of time, suggesting that the simulation has, in fact, turned up the sort of problem you'd want to be testing for.

If you want to adjust the "slowness", edit the Rules > Customize Rules file. Search for modem to see the latencies.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the response. I think you're right with the server timing out, which I'm going to also look into. I was able to get this to work a little better by commenting out the request-trickle-delay, and only using the response-trickle-delay. However, this doesn't really test for this scenario if the response is very small. Is there a way for fiddler to hold an entire response for a short period of time before releasing it?